# The pixel saver applet for Budgie is not working. What might I be doing wrong?

Tags: applet, extension, budgie, top-bar

I am currently running Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.1 LTS in a VirtualBox VM. I installed the "pixel saver" Budgie applet v 4.0 and verified in the applet menu and command line that it is installed. I've rebooted my VM as well as powered it off and back on but the pixel saver applet is simply not doing anything, nor can I find options or settings for it in any of the menus.

I ran the `apt-cache rdepends` command for it to check if I was missing any dependencies, but it came back with no results (I tested this command with other packages and it does list results for them). Has anyone else run into this issue or do you have any idea of what I could be missing here?

Comment: Have you actually added it to your panel using budgie desktop settings?

Comment: I wasn't initially seeing it in desktop settings (not sure if I overlooked it or it actually wasn't there). But yes, I've added it and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The pixel saver applet has to be added to the top panel in desktop settings in order to work. I did not see it listed in those settings initially (not sure if I overlooked it or it wasn't there until after a reboot). Now that I have added it to the panel, it is working fine.